# What does a well formatted regexp for filtering extensions look like?

Tags: php, regex

How to match 4 extensions with regexp?

I have tired this:

```
$returnValue = preg_match('/(pdf|jpg|jpeg|tif)/', 'pdf', $matches);
```

I dont know why I get 2 matches? I'm I something missed in the regexp?

```
array (
  0 => 'pdf',
  1 => 'pdf',
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `I dont know why I get 2 matches`

No you are getting only 1 match.

`$matches` has 2 entries:

1. `1st entry with index=0` is for the entire match of input by your regex
2. `2nd entry with index=1` is for the first matched group since your regex is enclosed in parentheses

If you want to avoid 2 entries you can use `non-capturing group`:

```
$returnValue = preg_match('/(?:pdf|jpg|jpeg|tif)/', 'pdf', $matches);
```

OR simply don't group them:

```
$returnValue = preg_match('/pdf|jpg|jpeg|tif/', 'pdf', $matches);
```

Comment: Could you write a basic example where the 1th and 2nd entry are not the same?

Comment: @2astalavista: Please check update now, you will get only 1 entry in resulting `$matches` array now. Also check out this demo: http://ideone.com/EAr9jE

Comment: Note: If the input is 'xpdf' or 'pdfx' there is also a match.

Comment: Yes that's correct and you can avoid that by using word boundaries as in: **`preg_match('/\b(?:pdf|jpg|jpeg|tif)\b/', $input, $matches);`**

Comment: I have seen in your bio, that you are located in India, is it a good place to live? I would like to go there once. Sorry for personal question.

Comment: Thanks for reply. `preg_match('/^(pdf|jpg|jpeg|tif)$/', $input, $matches);` is also seems OK.

Comment: Yes `^ and $` will only work when extension is at start and end of input text.